# Basic Vlan questions

Tags: networking, vlan

I've been "*awarded*" with IT infrastructure manager possition as I'm the "good with computers" guy in my small office. Nedless to say they have made a huge mistake, I have no clue....

I'd like to ask you something About Vlans, and first I'd like to show you our infrastructure:

We have one internet router that's pointing to a DMZ ip, wich is our Firewall/reouting device(sophos utm 120)
then we have a couple of switches (HP 2510 48p gigabit ethernet), 
connected to it, 
- we have personal computers,
- one windows 2008 server for domain controller dhcp, etc
- 3 wifi ap, Ubiquiti unifi ap

so, I would like to offer 2 different SSID on the 3 aps, one of wich is internal network (going trough firewall, etc) an the other is direct to our internet router (it has 4 ports, 1 to sophos and the other free)

I understand this has to be done trough Vlans, set up 2 vlans, and one of them phisically connect it directly to the router.

I know how to say to AP's that they mush show two SSID and assing a Vlan, but I do not know where to create the Vlans, is it on the Swithces? how should I wire it?

thanks!

(and sorry if it's a silly question)

Comment: I don't mean this harshly but you need someone who knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Begin my imagining a VLAN like a VPN for your LAN.  By tagging VLAN on traffic it's as if it's on a different LAN. Now to your specifics:
Create the VLAN on the UniFi wireless so the traffic will be tagged based on the SSID they connect to.  Then create the VLAN on the Sophos firewall you can segment the traffic and pass/or/block (your choice) traffic to other segments (VLANS).
NOTE: Each VLAN will need it's own IP block (DHCP,etc.) unless it's bridged to LAN (shared IP with LAN).  Typically your "guest" network will only have connection to WAN (Internet) while your "business wifi" network will have trust to LAN also.
The way to mess yourself up big on this project with VLAN is to apply them to ports on the switch. That will tag all traffic with that specific VLAN. Very useful in some situations but NOT yours.
By the way thanks for all the details about make and model of and implementation.  It does help!